# PULL Docker container/image

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this container in a POD running in kubernetes. Is it possible to pull it from docker when I have its unique ID that looks something like this

docker://ad6d5d32576ad3cb1fcaa59b564b8f6f22b079631080ab1a3bbac9199953eb7d

Comment: If you have a running pod, looking at its `kubectl describe` output should tell you the name of the image it is running. That image can be directly run/pulled using `docker run`.

Comment: the image was pulled from my google container registry to create the pod but I did some modification to it and I want the new image of the container running in that pod

Comment: If you went to the node running it, found the container, I guess you could do something like [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) but that is typically not recommended. It's easier and more maintainable to use dockerfiles.

Comment: why is that not recommended?

Comment: Compare the two: you run image in a container, make changes to it and commit it - you end up with a black box which does something. On the other hand, you can declare everything in the `Dockerfile` and end up with the same image - but it is clear what the changes from the source image were and give you the option to modify them later.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I just wanted to know if there is a way to commit that container in the kubernetes Pod to a dokcer image, just for fun. Again I appreciate your help